# How to create a Windows virtual machine using Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I am trying to create a Windows virtual machine using Hyper-V, but I have several issues. I tried following instructions on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/quick-create-virtual-machine), to use the "Quick Create":

I was expecting to see a vanilla Windows 10 OS here, but there is none. So, I created an `.iso` image, using the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-an-iso-file-for-windows-10-38547366-1dcb-7afd-1726-9eb222d72705). Through the "_Local installation source" I selected the ISO image, but I get this error message:

> Error
> The Operation failed.
> An unexpected error occurred: Logon failure: the user has not been granted the request logon type at this computer.
> (0x80070569).

Then I switched to "Hyper-V Manager" using the instructions on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/create-virtual-machine), but I get this error message:

> New Virtual Machine Wizard
> The server encountered an error while creating <virtualMachineName>.
> ...

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.** I asked a follow-up question [here](https://superuser.com/q/1719167/588662).

Comment: I suggest not using the “Quick Create” wizard.

Comment: Dear @DanielB thanks for your comment, though I would appreciate it if you could read my post thoroughly first. I did use "Quick Create" as you may see in the post.

Comment: Yes and I’m saying _not_ to use it. It won’t help you anyway and for diagnostic purposes you should absolutely try all ways to create a VM and many VM configuration combinations.

Comment: @DanielB the second half of the question is also about using the "Manager" to build a custom virtual machine.

Answer (score 5):

Your error message says: "The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."

Open the `secpol.msc` console, go to *Local Policies → User Rights Assignment*, and open the item **"Log on as a service"**. It should list the following two names:

```
NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES
NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines
```

If either of these items is missing (in particular the "Virtual Machines" one), <del>add it.</del> Well, it won't recognize those names when entered, so you'll probably need to find the `ntrights.exe` tool and run it like this (untested):

```
ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u *S-1-5-83-0
```

...or the [psprivilege](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/psprivilege/0.1.0) PowerShell module (this is currently not yet tested, either):

```
PS>   Install-Module -Name PSPrivilege -Scope AllUsers
PS>   $sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new("S-1-5-83-0")
PS>   Add-WindowsRight -Name SeServiceLogonRight -Account $sid
```

---

Windows distinguishes several logon types: interactive (full GUI or SSH logon), batch (e.g. Scheduled Tasks), service (actual services), network (SMB file shares). You're only able to log on to Windows because the whole "Users" group is explicitly listed under "Allow log on locally", and when you create a scheduled task to run under your account, the Task Scheduler tool adds you to the "Batch logon" list behind the scenes.

Comment: I'll figure out the correct procedure when I get back home. Until then, I found a workaround of creating a new _group_ with `*S-1-5-83-0` as a member (the `net localgroup` command does accept this) and granting it the rights.

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, I don't have `ntrights.exe` on my windows 10 21H2 version.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! I couldn't use gpupdate /force because I couldn't connect to the AD. The PowerShell statements solved it!

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/virtualization/starting-or-live-migrating-hyper-v-vms-fails), running the command

```
gpupdate /force
```

in an elevated command line, forces an update on group policies and now the `NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines` is there:

[image]

However, according to the discussions [this page](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3542), this error might happen again.