# Is there any way to have Windows containers using Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, sandbox

I want to have some isolated Windows containers preferably using built-in Hyper-V, on my Windows 10 Pro 21H2 machine. First I looked at the Windows Sandboxes. However, [it appears](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Sandbox-Utilities/issues/32#issuecomment-1115960794) as if Microsoft is intentionally ignoring the requests to have persistent sandboxes or the ability to take snapshots! (more discussion [here](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/158323-there-way-presist-data-windows-sandbox.html#post1935869))

Secondly, I looked into the Hyper-V virtual machines. After spending hours fixing [issues](https://superuser.com/q/1719153/588662) I had, I am being asked to provide a Windows license to install a Windows OS on the virtual machine. This, in my humble opinion, is absurd, given that I already have a Windows 10 Pro installed on my host computer. And I don't really need virtualization, but isolation.

Thirdly, it seems like one can have Windows containers using Docker Desktop (instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-10-and-11#prerequisites) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container)). However, I don't know how to install a vanilla windows container (in contrast to Windows Server the aforementioned instructions appear to be installed) without any Microsoft bloatware.

I would appreciate it if you could help me know how I can have some low-calorie isolated containers on my Windows Pro machine, without needing extra licenses.

**P.S.1.** I am being told that the Docker is most probably a dead end. I am trying the Hyper-V virtual machine again and also reading pages like [this one](https://call4cloud.nl/2021/08/sandbox-multiverse-of-madness/), hoping there is a workaround to take "snapshots" of Windows sandboxes.

**P.S.2.** I created an official feature request through Feedback Hub [here](https://aka.ms/AAguokc). Please do upvote it, if you agree there is a need for persistent containers with snapshot functionality. More discussions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Sandbox-Utilities/issues/32#issuecomment-1115960794) on GitHub, and [here](https://twitter.com/fsfarimani/status/1521439605731602432?s=20&t=oTyqbL148ZmKC2Yo1teiPA) on Twitter.

**P.S.3.** I am also looking into [Sandboxie](https://sandboxie-plus.com/), a Free and Open Source Software.

Comment: What part of the process exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @Ramhound at this moment I want to try Docker, but I am not sure if it is what I need and how it can be done. Maybe Sandboxes or Hyper-V virtual machines are a better option, I am not sure either.

Comment: A license isn't needed to install Windows 10/11 and both can be run without a license. I haven't installed Windows 11 yet, but if the Setup GUI isn't offering a way around providing a license, use an `unattend.xml` answer file and skip the license step _(IIRC, it's under the `windowsPE` configuration pass)_. AFAIK, the only bloatware that comes with Windows are the pre-installed Apps, which can be removed with Powershell. I haven't tried Docker integration yet since I use Hyper-V, but the bug linked to should have been resolved since it's 2yrs old - does restarting the VMMS resolve the issue?

Comment: Docker is a dead-end for your use case, RDP has been closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153861/enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-10-container unless you really only need to run console/services/IIS apps, in which case the Windows Server images https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images are actually as optimized as possible.

Comment: @JW0914 I am downloading a new `.iso` file. Maybe the image I already have is corrupt. 