# Unable to create Hyper-V VM on Windows 11 Pro host, with error 0x80070569

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-11

On my host machine (new work PC) running Windows 11 Pro, I want to create multiple VMs running Ubuntu Server. Previously I used VirtualBox for this purpose, but after my work PC was upgraded I was recommended Hyper-V.

After creating a new virtual switch in Hyper-V Manager, I try to create a VM using Quick Create, but I get an error message "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer. (0x80070569)" I get the same error message when I try to create the VM manually.

A quick Google search of that error code brings up several resources, but they are not easy for me to follow. Can anyone guide me on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Make sure BIOS (UEFI) has been properly set for Hardware Virtualization. Make sure the ISO you download is for desktop installation, not live on USB.  I have a machine with Hyper-V and a Kali VM and basic  VM Installation was straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Windows virtual machine using Hyper-V Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/1719153/how-to-create-a-windows-virtual-machine-using-hyper-v-manager)

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately it doesn't; I encountered other errors when I tried the proposed solutions

Comment: If you encounter errors, please indicate, what those errors are